# Can Windows 7, Vista, or XP notify me after 30 minutes, or at 2:30pm?

Tags: windows-7, windows, timer, alarm

Come to think about it, since Windows 3.0, Windows 95, 2000, ME, XP, Vista, and Windows 7, does any Windows have a capability of giving a "beep beep" notification to me, let's say I need to go meet somebody after 30 minutes?

Or give a "beep beep" at 2:30pm?

I hope to hear some sound instead of a pop up window as I may be writing something on the desk instead of looking at the computer.

I usually don't want to install 3rd party app for this purpose, as you never know what the app does or how trustworthy it is if it is not a popular app (like Firefox or Safari).

Does any version of Windows come with that capability?  I'd imagine it is an app that takes two days to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AT command? It's a simpler command line version of the Task Scheduler.

Try running something like this from a command prompt as a local admin:

`AT 1430 "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\mplayer2.exe c:\windows\media\tada.wav"`

Full options available with `AT /?`

Comment: It doesn't do the "in 30 minutes" request, but apart from that it seems to fit the bill

Answer (score 3):

Programs -> accessories -> System Tools --> Scheduled Tasks

Create a task that opens a sound file (wav or mp3 for example) and give it the time you want it to launch.

Make sure sound is up ! Get interrupted!

Comment: This is in windows XP. I think it exists on other versions of windows as well.  

When you create the task. .make sure to click on "browse" to select your sound file instead of a program to run.

Comment: this should be a solution except in the past it was too troublesome to set something running as a scheduled task.  The permission needs to be set right and need to test it.  If for some reason it didn't work then the time is missed.

Comment: well if the user can open a song or a sound file from somewhere in the computer and he has access to it.. then he or she can schedule a task to open that. When creating the task you specify the user you want

Answer (score 2):

Windows always used to come with Calender, but they took it out (I think with Windows 95), your best now is to use Microsoft Outlook for reminders and appointments - You can set sounds / music and alerts at intervals.

Comment: The Windows Vista Home Premium in my office and the Windows 7 Home Premium at home both have a free calendar out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Windows Live Mail from Microsoft's [Windows Live](http://download.live.com/), you'll get a Calendar that will give you alerts. It also works in conjunction with the online Live Calendar service.

And, unlike Outlook, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

if you happen to have MCE, there is a [Microsoft Powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/mcepowertoys.mspx) available that will play music/sound at a specified time. other than that, it's either scheduled tasks,  Outlook or a 'untrustworthy 3rd party app'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows 10’s Text-to-Speech capability and Cortana’s voice ([SpeechSynthesizer class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=netframework-4.7.2)), e.g.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech
$synthesizer = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
Start-Sleep 1800; $synthesizer.Speak('Hey!')
```

This will say *Hey!* after 30 minutes (1800 seconds).